# Rate of convergence of the given sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Consider the sequence: $x_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n+n}$. Find the rate of convergence of the sequence $\{x_n\}$.

For this, first we find the limit of the sequence $\{x_n\}$.

We have,

\begin{align*}
\lim_n x_n&=\lim_n\left[\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n+n}\right]\\
&=\lim_n\frac 1n \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac rn}\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\log(2)
\end{align*}

To find the rate of convergence we have to find out the value $p$ so that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1}-l|}{|x_n-l|^p}$ exists non-zero finitely.

I am unable to find out this limit. Any help please ?

Comment: Since you use rectangles for $\frac{1}{1+x}$, why don't you use the rate of convergence of the rectangle method? it is in $1/n$ I think

Answer (score 1):

All of what you want lies in the rectangle method, let us calculate

$$ \ln(2) - x= \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^\frac{k}{n} \frac{1}{1 +x} - \frac{1}{1 +\frac{k}{n}} dx \geq 0$$
A quick study of the derivative would give us quickly that $|\ln(2) - x_n| \leqslant M/n$ for some $M$, but we need to show that we can't do better...

$$ \int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^\frac{k}{n} \frac{1}{1 +x} - \frac{1}{1 +\frac{k}{n}} dx \geq \int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^\frac{k- 1/2}{n} \frac{1}{1 +x} - \frac{1}{1 +\frac{k}{n}} \geq \frac{1}{2n} \left(\frac{1}{1 + \frac{2k-1}{2n}} -  \frac{1}{1 + \frac{k}{n}}\right) \\
= \frac{1}{4n^2}\cdot\frac{1}{(1 + \frac{k}{n})(1 + \frac{2k-2}{2n})}\geq \frac{1}{16n^2}$$
So we get
$$\ln(2) - x \geq n \cdot \frac{1}{16n^2} = \frac{1}{16n}$$
This gives you directly that $p = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

For  $f\in C^1[1,2]$ there holds
$$\left |{1\over n}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}f\left ({k\over n}\right)-\int\limits_1^2f(x)\,dx\right | \le {M\over n}\quad (*)$$
where $M=\displaystyle \max_{1\le x\le 2}|f'(x)|.$
We have $$\log (1+x)=x-{x^2\over 2}+O(x^3),\quad 0\le x<1$$
Hence
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{1\over k} =\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\log\left (1+{1\over k}\right )+{1\over 2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{1\over k^2}+O(n^{-2})
$$
Next $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\log\left (1+{1\over k}\right )=\log{2n+1\over n+1}\\ =\log 2+\log \left (1-{1\over 2n+2}\right )\\
= \log 2-{1\over 2n+2}+O(n^{-2})=\log 2-{1\over 2n}+O(n^{-2})$$
Applying $(*)$ we get
$${1\over 2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{1\over k^2}={1\over 2n^2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{1\over ({k\over n})^2} ={1\over 2n} \int\limits_1^2{1\over x^2}\,dx+O(n^{-2})\\
={1\over 4n}+O(n^{-2})$$
Summarizing
$$x_n-\log 2= \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\log\left (1+{1\over k}\right )-\log 2=-{1\over 4n}+O(n^{-2})$$
Thus $p=1.$

Comment: @CarlChristian You are right. I have never come across the rate of convergence. I will modify the answer.

Comment: +1. I was very happy to see so many details written out in full. Your proof is very simple and clear.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use harmonic numbers
$$x_n=H_{2 n}-H_n$$
Now, when $p$ is large
$$H_p=\log (p)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ whic makes
$$x_n=\log (2)-\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{1}{16   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)=\log (2)-\frac{1}{4 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: Is there a short proof of the central asymptotic expansion? I believe that it is normally derived use Euler's summation formula, but I am hoping that you know something better.